# How to use a CarouselView in .NET MAUI C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am new to .NET MAUI and found the CarouselView control and am having a hard time using it.
I created a simple app that displays names of recipes. In the MainPage.xaml I have a CarouselView as follows:

```
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Recipe">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

When I try to run the code above using Visual Studio running for a "Windows Machine" a white window pops up but never fills, the loading wheel just keeps spinning as the page is unresponsive.

If I switch the code to use a collection view as shown below the app launches just fine and displays all the recipe names.

```
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Recipe">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

I tried to follow this sample code in the Microsoft's documents but haven't made any progress yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/?view=net-maui-7.0

If someone could point out the problem in my implementation using a CarouselView and/or point me to another example on how to use a CarouselView I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: There seems to be a memory leak when I run the CarouselView code above. I left the app "frozen" at the white loading screen for 90 minutes and Visual Studio's resource monitor shows it's taking over 4GB of Process Memory. Clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: A memory leek is nothing weird for MAUI. I know at least two issues that cause memory leaks, and I am still waiting for backport. (Otherwise I have to wait for .NET 8.)

Comment: Maybe it's related to the BindingContext ? Also most of the times where I had a white screen were related to bad dependcy injection (if thats help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue on the windows platform. I tested on the Android platform and it works well. You can report it as an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) about the CarouselView on the windows platform.

In addition, you can use the Collectionview by setting the `ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"` to achieve the CarouselView format.